# Can I run my own instance of google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to understand how feasible it would be to spin up my own instance of a Colaboratory server that I could run within a closed network. Using the public version is unfortunately not yet an option in my company. I would really like to have something equivalent that I could use internally, which has all of the nice features such as collaborative editing.

Has anyone tried doing this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to spin up a full instance of the Colab service; i.e., the bits that integrate with GSuite / Docs / GCP / TPUs.

But, you can run local backends using the instructions here:

http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html